# The following code returns the value twice, once encoded in JSON :

Tags: php, json

```
$sql = " select * from Papers where IND < 317";

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode(array("Papers"=>$resultArray));
}
// Close connections
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

When I open my php file on the local host my rows from mysql database are correctly be converted into json objects however they are being duplicated.

Comment: You probably can just do: array_push($resultArray, $row);
Since you dont need to assign this to a variable.

Comment: What does that mean exactly, they're "duplicated"?! What does the result look like exactly?

Answer (score 0):

FIXED - Had to clean my database. I had ran several instances of the insert statement that had caused many duplicate instances.

Answer (score -1):

You probably can just do:

```
 array_push($resultArray, $row);
```

Since you dont need to assign this to a variable.

Comment: How would this solve the person problem? This should have been a comment

Comment: Yeah, you're right, this is not an answer. I only had one sip of coffee.

Comment: Sorry guys just got it fixed, was my own stupidity, I had to clean my actual database, I had ran the insert query more than once by accident so there was more than one instance of each value.